# three.js Switching objects on click

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to hide/reveal objects with the click of a button. i.e. click button on a GUI and obj1 is hidden and obj2 is revealed. I was told to do this using

```
 object.traverse(object.visible=false);
```

but it does not seem to work.

Here is how I'm rendering my objects

```
var gal = jsonLoader.load( "model/galmodel.js", addModelToScene ) ;
gal.traverse(gal.visible = false);
```

Can anyone point me into the right direction on how to make this work? And the command that will hide/reveal the objects on click?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time i checked, the traverse function was a callback.
So you would need to do something like this:

```
gal.traverse(function(child){
   child.visible = false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
I also tried that but I just get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'traverse' of undefined.

Comment: Well, you will have to make sure your "gal" variable is set of course. You should check the loader examples on the three.js homepage how loading is done properly. As I recall, the load-Function is callback-based, too so you will maybe have to set "gal" inside your callback function addModeltoScene? Not sure what the jsonloader.load function itself returns

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. My variable "gal" is defined as : var gal = jsonLoader.load( "model/galmodel.js", addModelToScene ) ;

It is also set inside the addModeltoScene as: 
function addModelToScene(gal) {} etc. 
The object renders properly, I just want to be able to show/hide it through whatever function permits it. The traverse function continues telling me that it is undefined. 
Thank you again.

Comment: Figured it out. Just simply had to add that function inside the addModeltoScene function for that object. Thank you very much.
Now I just need to be able to hide this object and show another with the push of a button. Any ideas?